# How to Specify Eclipse Proxy Authentication Credentials?

Tags: eclipse, proxy, credentials

I'm using the latest version of Eclipse Galileo and I have to access the web from behind a proxy. I see where I can set the internet settings to manual and specify a proxy but there's no way to specify my authentication credentials that I can see and it doesn't prompt me for them either. So I'm not able to hit any plugin update sites etc... Does anyone else have this issue or know a good workaround? Or is there a better version of Eclipse to use?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to Window → Preferences → General → Network Connections. In the Active Provider combo box, choose "Manual". In the proxy entries table, for each entry click "Edit..." and supply your proxy host, port, username and password details.

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

Comment: wouldn't that involve putting my password in plain text? also what is the format of the string?

Comment: 1. If you want Eclipse (or any tool, for that matter) to perform authentication for you, then you have to tell it your password :-) Why is that a problem?
2. The format of which string?

Comment: Eclipse 3.4+ will automatically encrypt your proxy authentication info using a master password as part of its secure storage feature. http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-securestorage-works.htm

Comment: After these steps Eclipse Mars (4.5.1) will crash on startup.

Comment: What to do if my computer use Automatic Configuration Script?

Answer (score 42):

If you have still problems, try deactivating ("Clear") SOCKS

see: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=281384
"I believe the reason for this is because it uses the SOCKS proxy
instead of the HTTP proxy if SOCKS is configured."

Comment: Indeed. I suffered with Eclipse 3.6 behind a corporate proxy with this issue. Clearing password for SOCKS solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: This worked to me on Eclipse Kepler. Holy God, how I would know?

Comment: thanks mate!!,,this worked for me in eclipse mars 2 as well

Comment: Worked for me also on Eclipse Neon

Comment: Worked for me on Eclipse Oxygen (Release 4.7.1, Build id: 20170914-1200).

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me. But i can only access Eclipse Marketplace, when trying to install a third party plugin using Help --> Install New Software, its not allowing me to. Facing same error "http" authentication required.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the workaround:

In eclipse.ini write the following:

```
-vmargs
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors= org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
-Dhttp.proxyHost=*myproxyhost*
-Dhttp.proxyPort=*myproxyport*
-Dhttp.proxyUser=*proxy username*
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=*proxy password*
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
```

After starting eclipse verify, that you use the Manual proxy method.

HTH

Answer (score 10):

Window → Preferences → General → Network Connections 
then under "Proxy ByPass" click "Add Host" and enter the link from which you will be getting your third-party plugin;
that's it bingo, now it should get the plugin no problem.

Comment: Awesome. I wonder why it's no accepted as a correct answer. Thank you Amir.

Comment: "I have to access the web from behind a proxy" is mentioned in the question. You tell him to bypass it. How is this an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 10):

I struggle with this constantly, as it seems it is a different solution every time a new version of Eclipse is released. Here is a solution that doesn't involve displaying your password in the .ini file.

In Eclipse go to Window > Preferences > General > security Secure Storage

In the Password tab click on the "Change Password" button
Fill in the security questions. Don't make them to hard. Finish

Now go to Window > Preferences > General > Network connections. Choose "Manual" from drop down. Double click "HTTP" option and enter the Host, Port, Username and Password. Finish

Now go to Window > Preferences > General > security Secure Storage

In the Password tab click on the "Recover Password" button
Fill in the security questions. Finish

Eclipse now stores your username and password

Comment: Hello Gareth, Your Answer is not Related to this Question.

Comment: It is definitively related. This stupid Eclipse kept discarding my proxy credentials silently again and again, until I find this answer and delete the secure storage stuff. It does now remember the credentials and I can bypass the proxy.

Answer (score 2):

This sometime works, sometime no.

I have installed 1 Eclipse - works.

Installed second - doesn't work.

And I cann't figure why!

After some time may be found a solution.

Need delete all setting for proxy (included credentials).
And re-insert for new.

After this for me getting work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to fill only the HTTP schema

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line at the end of your eclipse.ini file

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

Answer (score 0):

For eclipse Mar1 : - 
Window > Preferences > General > Network connections. Choose "Manual" from drop down. Double click "HTTP" option and enter the Host, Port, Username and Password. Apply and Finish,,it will work as expected...