# installing SVN Kit connectors proxy authentication error

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive, svnkit, eclipse-luna

I have installed the most recent version of subversion svn and then I start up eclipse to download the connector.  Pick the most recent SVN Kit (1.8.5) and then I get this error:

Problems occurred while performing installation: HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: 
http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/4.0/luna-site/content.xml
See error log for details.

Any thoughts as to what is going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Specify Eclipse Proxy Authentication Credentials?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940984/how-to-specify-eclipse-proxy-authentication-credentials)

Comment: @bahrep Maybe not a duplicate. May be related to a bug in Eclipse 4.4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using [NTLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) proxy?

Support for NTLM proxy authentication is broken in Eclipse 4.4 Luna: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422665 . This breaks at least SVN connector installation and Eclipse Marketplace.

Workaround is to put following somewhere after `-vmargs` option in `eclipse.ini`:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

Comment: Workaround worked for me with Eclipse 4.5.2, thanks.