# Eclipse Luna Not Storing Proxy Authentication Username and Password

Tags: eclipse, authentication, proxy

I'm trying to get Eclipse Luna (on Debian 8) to connect to the Internet via a WiFi proxy that requires authentication. I am able to set the proxy host, port, username and password after which I apply the settings and close the dialog. The next time I open it, it does not have the username and password settings, although the host and port are retained correctly. The Active Provider is set to Manual as required.

For some reason, it doesn't seem to be saving the authentication details and I'm not able to connect to the Internet.

Is this a bug or I'm I doing something wrong?

Also, in what file does Eclipse store the proxy settings? Maybe I can go in there and make the changes directly if this is a GUI problem.

Edit: A look at the Error Log gives a vital clue. It says: No secure storage modules found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this issue by adding the proxy settings to the eclipse.ini file as specified in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940984/how-to-specify-eclipse-proxy-authentication-credentials).

```
-vmargs
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
-Dhttp.proxyHost=*myproxyhost*
-Dhttp.proxyPort=*myproxyport*
-Dhttp.proxyUser=*proxy username*
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=*proxy password*
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
```

Comment: The space should be removed in this line after the equals sign, otherwise it will not work: -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4