# how do I completely remove Eclipse's stored network authentication information and proxy information?

Tags: eclipse

Where does eclipse store its network preferences.I tried deleting the workspace, the eclipse installation directory, where ever I found eclipse in c:\user\appdata. But eclipse seems to some how populate with my username and password but not the proxy address. I would like to have a absolutely clean eclipse install and how do I achieve that?

Comment: Here is the contemporary solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34204939/715269. (works from Eclipse 4.3 up)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, go to Window → Preferences → General → Network Connections. In the Active Provider combo box, choose "Manual". In the proxy entries table, for each entry click "Edit..." and do whatever you want.

Copied from here:
[How to Specify Eclipse Proxy Authentication Credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940984/how-to-specify-eclipse-proxy-authentication-credentials)

Comment: once you have entered you credentials, unzip eclipse to some other location and you will see you proxy settings. I want to know where these settings are stored.